# SOLVED | Solidity: the bool values returned correctly on Remix IDE but always return "false" on JS

Tags: solidity, dapps

This question looks silly but it drives me crazy because I cant find a solution. I will make it clear below.

I use useDApp framework and with [useCall](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/api%20reference/hooks/#usecall) hook. I can get correctly values returned from Solidity functions and everything works very perfectly. But wrong with these 2 functions:

```
function showRemainingDate(uint _id) public view returns(uint) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < users[msg.sender].numberOfCards; i++) {
        if (users[msg.sender].purchase[i].card.id == cards[_id].id) {
            return 30*86400 - (block.timestamp - users[msg.sender].purchase[i].purchaseDate);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function checkPurchase(uint _id) public view returns (bool) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < users[msg.sender].numberOfCards; i++) {
        if (users[msg.sender].purchase[i].card.id == cards[_id].id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

After having deployed on Remix, I imported its address and `ABI` for my dApp project then used [useCall](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/api%20reference/hooks/#usecall) hook like this:

```
export function useCheckPurchase(index) {
  const { value: checkPurchase } = useCall({
    contract: contract,
    method: "checkPurchase",
    args: [index],
  }) ?? {};
  return checkPurchase;
}

export function useShowRemainingDate(index) {
  const { value: showRemainingDate } = useCall({
    contract: contract,
    method: "showRemainingDate",
    args: [index],
  }) ?? {};
  return showRemainingDate;
}
```

The weird points start here, if I use `purchaseCard` hook/function (no matter on JS or Remix) and then `console.log` the values (just for example):

```
console.log(useCheckPurchase(3))
console.log(parseInt(useShowRemainingDate(3)))
```

It would always return `false` and `0` for all parameter:

[image: values appearing on console]

While the values would always return correctly on Remix:

[image: checkPurchase] [image: showRemainingDate]

This is a very weird bug, Im sure there arent any typo in the names.

This is the contract address `0x29588f4714223bd492ce6500D6CEE0eCD4f1c51e` in my examples and [this is my Solidity code](https://pastebin.com/VE5L6siY).

Thank you everyone, any answer from you guys are all appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the same wallet to connect remix and call functions in js?

Comment: @SteveGerrad of course yes, sir. everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally know the reason. 
After changing `msg.sender` into my wallet address on Solidity code, it worked perfectly.
From here, I can show that the problem is with `msg.sender`.

And this is the solution post, you guys can read more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908375/solidity-function-returns-empty-array-on-ethersjs-hardhat-but-not-in-remix-ide

Hope this will help someone encountering my question.